# How do i use a variable that is defined inside of a function, outside of a function?

Tags: python, function, variables

Here is my function:

```
def playNovice(marbles):
        import random
        rand = random.randint(1,(0.5*marbles))
        print('Computer takes: ', rand)

a = rand + rand
print(a)
```

I want to reuse the variable rand. I have a feeling it might be:

```
global rand
```

I did try that but it didn't work, so i assume i used it wrong or its wrong all together.

Comment: Add `return rand` at the end of the function and then `rand = playNovice(...)` to get it out of it. `global rand` does a different thing (just search for it on SO) and in most cases it should be avoided.

Comment: never use global if you don't know when it's helpful. And put the `import` at the beginning of the file, so you can see the dependencies to other modules at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `return` to give values back to the caller:

```
import random

def playNovice(marbles):
    rand = random.randint(1,(0.5*marbles))
    print('Computer takes: ', rand)
    return rand

rand = playNovice(6)
a = rand + rand
print(a)
```

Comment: but each time that function runs, a random number is produced so each time that i assign that number to a variable the number will be d

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do use `global rand`.

You also need to add in `playNovice(number of marbles)` for the function to run. Just defining the function is like setting a variable but not printing it.

```
def playNovice(marbles):
    global rand
    import random
    rand = random.randint(1,(0.5*marbles))
    print('Computer takes: ', rand)

playNovice(num)
a = rand + rand
print(a)
```

The above should work.

Just as a sidenote, it is best to put all global declarations at the start of a function so it is easier to read when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `global rand` but it is not the ideal approach. (I agree that returning values is a better way to tackle this issue). This is an example of how to use `global rand` in this case.

When you do

```
a = rand + rand
```

You are referencing a `rand` that has not been declared yet.

An example showing the modification of `rand` with `global rand` would look like:

```
def playNovice(marbles):
        global rand
        import random
        rand = random.randint(1,(0.5*marbles))
        print('Computer takes: ', rand)

rand = 10
print(rand)
playNovice(2)
print(rand)
```

The results would look like:

```
10
('Computer takes: ', 1)
1
```